# Change the order/flip the xtab in R

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
    result = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), weight = c(0.126, 
    0.5, 0.8, 1.5, 5.3, 2.2, 3.2, 1.1, 0.1, 1.3, 2.5)), .Names = c("region", 
"result", "weight"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am producing a weighted xtab:

```
df$region <- factor(df$region)
result <- xtabs(weight ~ result + region, data=df)
result
```

Which is:

```
      region
result     a     b
     0 6.926 6.900
     1 1.300 3.500
```

How can I flip the xtab around so the region and result variables are the other way around (i.e. region as rows and result as columns).

I thought this might work, but alas no!

```
result <- xtabs(region + (weight ~ result), data=df)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse the order of entries:

```
 xtabs(weight ~ region + result, data=df)
```